# How can I convert a Html file to a pdf file in Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, pdf

Which library or component can do this in a easy way and not too expensive.

Edit:
Oeps: I should have informed you that it is web app. and we can't rely on the the user have PDF driver installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [Gnostice eDocEngine](http://www.gnostice.com/eDocEngine_VCL.asp), a document creation toolkit for VCL with full source code. It creates/converts to Pdf as well. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to display the HTML file in a `TWebBrowser` (as described [here](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0104_4.htm)) and to print it (as described [here](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0504_5.htm)) to a PDF Printer (e.g. [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/products/pdfcreator)).

Answer (score 1):

[PowerPdf](http://www.est.hi-ho.ne.jp/takeshi_kanno/powerpdf/) is free. It doesn't directly convert from html to pdf but you may be able to parse the html and use it to generate a close facsimile.

Comment: How disappointing, page no longer exists... https://sourceforge.net/projects/powerpdf/

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this without the user manipulation (transparent for te user) you can read [this (PDFFactory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925348/printing-to-pdf/925658#925658).

Regards.