# Print a specific tabsheet of a form in pdf format

Tags: forms, delphi, pdf, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [printing to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925348/printing-to-pdf)

I need to print a complete tabsheet(with all its components) of a delphi 10 form into a pdf file. All the components must be freeware, plus the user should be able to do it without installing any 3rd party apps.Can someone give me a help with the basics?

Comment: may be take active screen image and then to pdf

Comment: could u be a bit more specific about the pdf part?

Comment: Ok then, skip the adobe component part. Do you know any way of printing my whole form to a pdf file?

Comment: This question is essentially equivalent to "What is the best freely available Delphi PDF library?"

Comment: nope,this question is equivalent to "How can I print an entire form to pdf"

Comment: You print your form to a PDF printer in the same way you print the same form to any other kind of printer. The only difference is that you will use a virtual printer that outputs a PDF file instead of outputting a sheet of paper. So, all you need to do is google for a free PDF printer component that you can use from Delphi.

Comment: Once you have a PDF library, then printing a tabsheet to it is going to be simple. Anyway, do you want to print the entire form, or do you want to print just a tabsheet?

Comment: I would like to print just a tabsheet. Do u happen to know any pdf library? no fancy stuff needed, just sth simple to get the job done.

Comment: More than one question here, or the question is how to print to a pdf (exact duplicate) or the question is how to print a tabsheet (but looks like @user1565990) is not kind enough to clarify on that point.

Comment: pdf libraries usualy commercial(ex. Gnostic, wPDF). Using virtual printer is not an option, because your requirement ...without installing any 3rd party apps. I think there is one free one on sourceforge, with limited capabilities, but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 2):

I will make these suggestions:
1) CutePDF (3rd party app) - free, but still 3rd party
2) Write a report using Quick Reports - believe it is still free/available in Delphi and then output it to PDF - I  know Quick Reports can output to PDF.
-D